# Set default query by var1 & var2

Tags: php, default

I have two variables: var1 & var2. I want to display var1 default, but if var1 is empty or null, show var2. Regardless of whether or not it has var2 value

the basic:

```
$var1:'';
$var2:'volvo";
$var3 = empty($var1)? $var2 : $var1;
```

working.

but the complete script with query:

```
<form class="form-wrapper cf" name="searchForm" method="GET" action="<?=$PHP_SELF?>">
    <input type="text"id="searchBox" autofocus="autofocus" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" name="q" value="<?=$var1?>" title="Search Products" />
    <button type="submit"class="red-button"  value="Search" id="search-submit" ><span class="search-icon"></span>Search</button>
</form>
```

is not working only $var2 shows up.

Comment: You're not using `$var3` in the script with the form.

Comment: you need to output $var3 in the input -> value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your three lines of code will always put $var2 in $var3, as far as your $var1 is just declared as empty before.

In your html script, where do you want to show the result ? If its in the input, you have to echo $var3 instead of $var1.